# Knowing $2xf(x)+x^2f'(x) = \frac{e^x}{x}$ and $f(2) = \frac{e^2}{8}$. Does f(x) has a local maximum or local minimum at $x = 2$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

$2xf(x)+x^2f'(x) = \frac{e^x}{x}$.
$f(2) = \frac{e^2}{8}$.
And how to prove it?

What I can get is $f'(2) = 0$ and $f''(2) = 0$ but I think that's not enough.

Comment: What's the second derivative at $2$?

Comment: @Gaffney $f''(2) = 0$.

Comment: hint:you can solve by this way $$2xf(x)+x^2f'(x)=(x^2f(x))'\\\to\\(x^2f(x))'=\frac{e^x}{x}\\ \frac{d(x^2f(x))}{dx}=\frac{e^x}{x}\\ \int {d(x^2f(x))}dx=\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx\\
x^2f(x)=\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx\\$$ then apply $f(2)=\frac{e^2}{8}$

Comment: @Khosrotash I don't understand how to 'apply' that?

Comment: Did you had ,differential equation before (now) ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes i know a bit. Can you write down the steps?

Comment: Do you mean @x=2  has local min or max ?

Comment: @Khosrotash That is what i want to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you found the second derivative...  Keep doing that until you have a non-zero derivative and use this:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtremumTest.html

Comment: $$f(2)=\frac{e^2}{8} ,f'(2)=0 ,f''(2)=0\\(x^2f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x})'''\\0f(x)+3(2)f'(x)+3(2x)f''(x)+x^2f'''(x)=\frac{x^3e^x-2x(x-1)e^x}{x^4}\\f'''(2)=\frac{e^2}{16}>0$$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your first step there, bu the idea is right.

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes those are the correct steps. Thanks.